# Is it possible to get "find -exec" expand backticks for each file found?

Tags: linux, bash

Here's a command that works fine:

```
echo Blah: `stat -c %a .`
```

Is it possible to get `find -exec` to execute this same thing for every file found, with `{}` in place of `.`?

Comment: Backticks can't work there because they are evaluated once before `find` is even executed and the result is used as a static parameter for find.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The best way to do that is to use positional parameters. And `$()` is [preferred](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082) for command substitution ove backticks because it's more readable (isn't confused with single quotes) and can be easily nested without having to do a lot of escaping.

```
find . -exec bash -c 'echo Blah: $(stat -c %a "$@")' _ {} \;
```

The underscore is a placeholder for `$0`.

Comment: "The underscore is a placeholder for `$0`" -- To clarify, the literal string "_" is being passed into the `bash` command as the 0th argument (`$0`) so that the `{}` is used as the first argument (`$1`). Essentially, the `_` is like adding an extra null value to take up space so that the parameters line up with the `bash` command properly. To understand this, see that `bash -c 'echo \$0: $0, \$1: $1, \$2: $2' _ a b` prints out `$0: _, $1: a, $2: b`. This is necessary because `$@` starts at `$1`, not at `$0`.

Answer (score 6):

What for?

```
find ... -printf 'Blah: %m\n'
```

Or use `bash -c` if you really have to:

```
 find . -exec bash -c 'echo Blah: `stat -c %a {}`' \;
```

Comment: Thanks for solving my immediate problem, but I'm still curious to know if backticks can be used as described. Just to widen my horizons.

Comment: You'd have to invoke the shell via `bash -c` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to use them (AFAIK) is to place them in a bash script file and use the script in -exec. Same thing with `$()`

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget `xargs` !
Your example would invoke a new shell process for each file found.

I would prefer this:

`find ... | xargs stat -c "Blah: %a"`

`find` outputs a list of everything found, `xargs` reads a list of arguments on `stdin` and executes its parameter with those arguments on the command line, building as long a command line as possible.
It works because `stat`, as most other proper commands/programs do, take any number of parameters. (compare `ls`, `rm` and `echo` for instance)

If you think it's absolutely neccessary to launch a new process for each file, use `xargs -n 1` to only pass `1` parameter to each command.
That way you can mimick the inefficient methods like this:

`find ... | xargs -n 1 stat -c "Blah: %a"`

(Try it on a big filesystem on a slow computer and time the differences!)

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but I *need* those backticks. Obviously my example is simplified and uses echo + stat; the real script uses neither echo nor stat, so your trick of putting them together into stat's format string doesn't help at all.